# Побитовые операции для области памяти

Tags: c++, c, ассемблер

```
uint64_t a;
uint64_t b;
uint64_t a_and_b = a & b;
uint64_t a_or_b  = a | b;
```

Как сделать аналогичное для произвольной области памяти (например для `uint64_t[n]`)? Есть ли какие-то особые команды ОС или ассемблера для этого?

p.s. имеется ввиду что-то, кроме обхода всей этой области памяти по кускам (`uint8_t`, `uint16_t` и т.д.) и выполнение необходимой операции для каждого куска

Comment: В общем, да. Смотрите [SSE](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/SSE)/[AVX](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/AVX)

Comment: В смысле? Вы не хотите руками писать цикл и ищете инструкцию, которая сама обработает блок памяти без явного написания цикла?

Comment: Скорее всего нет, поскольку за 9 лет с префиксами REP я видел только строковые инструкции типа SCASB, MOVSB и типа того.

Comment: Напишите функцию с простым циклом и посмотрите что компилятор делает для разных архитектур (unroll loops, xmmN/ymmN регистры использовать — это работа для компилятора).

Answer (score 1):

Используйте хотя бы ММХ расширение команд для х86 (https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/MMX). Если на Вашем компе есть DSP - процессор обработки цифровых сигналов, то эта задачка - как раз для него.

Comment: Я для таких случает даже с помощью  `__emit__` вставлял mmx команды.